# Concatenate 2 consecutive words in a list

Tags: python, list, nlp

I have multiple list of word tokens as follows:

```
sentence =  "Pay ninety dollar in ninety days"
a = ['Pay','ninety','dollar,'in','ninety','days']
```

I want to find and concatenate 2 consecutive words:

```
x = ['ninety','days']
result = ['Pay','ninety','dollar','in','ninety_days'] or "Pay ninety dollar in ninety_days"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use simple `str.replace`?

```
sentence =  "Pay bill in ninety days"
x = ['ninety', 'days']
replaced = sentence.replace(' '.join(x), '_'.join(x))

>>> 'Pay bill in ninety_days'
```

This also supports any number of words you want to concat.
Note that it is case sensitive as well as white spaces sensitive.